# Rails : How to use "current_user" in a class_eval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to use the method `current_user` in a class_eval.
For now I get :

> > undefined method `current_user'

**lib/extends/votes_controller_extended.rb**

```
VotesController.class_eval do
  def create
    ...

    @current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

I guess the `current_user` is not available at this stage... But may be there is a way to get it anyway.

Comment: Do you get the error at define time or later, when you call the generated `create`?

Comment: Why are you using `class_eval`? At a glance, this looks like something to be solved with inheritance.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I get the error when I launch the server.

Comment: @TomLord I use class_eval because I'd like to override the create method from VotesController

Comment: @Orsay That sounds like something to be solved with inheritance.

Comment: @TomLord can you give me an example for my case please ?

Comment: @Orsay `class MyCustomisedVotesController < VotesController; def create; ....; end; end`

Comment: So you have dynamically created a instance method for the controller, that's cool. Have you also made a route for it? Have you tried hitting the route?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're doing with the `class_eval` and why you can't just use inheritance to overwrite the `VotesController`, but `current_user` is set after you run `authenticate_user!`, so, this should work:

```
VotesController.class_eval do
  def create
    authenticate_user!
    ...

    @current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: In this app I cannot edit the existed files. If I want to edit something I have to patch it. That's why i'm using a `class_eval` and cannot use inheritance.
I tried your proposal, but it doesn't work, I still have the current_user issue